# Is there a way by which we can mix plane geometry and calculus

Tags: calculus, geometry

Like we mix trigonometry and geometry to solve some of the difficult geometry question similarly can we mix plane geometry (geometry of which includes angles, sides of polygon, circles etc) and calculus. Such that after using that techniques
we can solve questions like finding relations between the sides of triangle and radius of it's in-circle.
Thanks in advance for your response.

Comment: [Differential geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_geometry)

Comment: But first, [analytic geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_geometry).

Comment: The ancient Greeks used the techniques of plane geometry plus an intuitive limiting process called the method of exhaustion to solve problems that we would now approach via calculus e.g. finding expressions for the volume of 3D shapes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mathematics was and still is primarily a collection of techniques to help solve problems. Think of them as mental tools. Given any particular problem there may be an obvious tool choice which will do the job, but there is no reason why several different kinds of tools may not be used together to help solve the problem. It has happened many times that techniques in one area of mathematics are used to solve problems in another area of mathematics. As one example, many trigonometry problems are solved using arithmetic and algebra. Another example is analytic geometry which uses arithmetic and algebra to solve geometry problems. The differential and integral calculus was developed as advanced tools designed to be combined with the use of analytic geometry to solve geometry problems.

To answer your question, here is one particular problem. Suppose we have a fixed circle and we need to find the triangle inscribed in that circle which has the maximum area. This can be solved using differential calculus which uses derivatives to solve general maximum/minimum problems.